# Interaction in logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, interaction

I'm running a logistic regression in R with the function glm(). I would like to add an interaction between two independent variables, and I know that I can use * or : to link the two terms. Example: I have a categorical independent variable and a continuous independent variable and the interaction can be sex*weight or sex:weight. While I understand how to interpret the result of the first option, I have no idea how to interpret the second one, considering that it does not create a reference category as the interaction with * does.

Comment: I added an answer explaining the difference between the * and : specification. But I am not sure this is what you were asking. If your question is mainly *why* the interaction term in the ":"-only model is different (and why this model is probably not useful) you will probably find multiple posts on this on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terms `sex*weight` and `sex:weight` have different meanings. The first one (*) is a shorthand for `sex + weight + sex:weight`, that is, for including each parameter AND the interaction. `sex:weight` only adds the interaction term. Therefore the resulting models differ.

As far as I know, models should always include the lower level terms which are involved in interactions. Otherwise, the interaction can not be interpreted (easily), see for instance here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/133735

```
#model including both parameters and their interaction with "*"
m1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~  Petal.Width * Petal.Length, data = iris)
coef(m1)

             (Intercept)              Petal.Width             Petal.Length Petal.Width:Petal.Length 
               4.5771709               -1.2393154                0.4416762                0.1885887
```

```
#model including both pars and interaction (all terms spelled out)
m2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~  Petal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width:Petal.Length, data = iris)
coef(m2)
             (Intercept)              Petal.Width             Petal.Length Petal.Width:Petal.Length 
               4.5771709               -1.2393154                0.4416762                0.1885887
```

```
#model only including the interaction
m3 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~  Petal.Width:Petal.Length, data = iris)
coef(m3)
             (Intercept) Petal.Width:Petal.Length 
               4.9704818                0.1506457
```