# How do I to run GLM with interaction term and multiple non-interaction variables in R?

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I have a data set that shows clear differences in observations of my dependent variable based on very clear periods of activity (e.g., month 1 counts are very high, month 2 counts are medium, month 3 counts are low). My hypothesis is that these differences in month are not explained by environmental variables, and that environmental variables do not affect counts in months of high activity (e.g., there's some important biological drive for these differences which overrides any environmental conditions over that period) but that within months of low counts, count number is explained by environmental variables. How do I code the GLM model for this? Would it look like this:

```
#activity is categorical variable of high, med, low
GLM <- counts ~ activity + temp + percip + time + activity * temp + percip + time
```

Comment: Comment on the motivation for the question here: if your hypothesis is that there is no association between differences and environmental variable, you don't even need to look at data to know with certainty the hypothesis is false since basic probability tells us Pr(X=x) = 0 in continuous space. If it's instead "I won't find an association," that's a bit silly -- absence of evidence is not evidence of absence since bad/little data, bad statistical models, and other (non-)random error can explain the absence. See here https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/equivalencetest.html

Comment: Note also that you're modeling a time series. In generalized linear models, unmodeled autocorrelation of the error terms (which is essentially guaranteed in every substantive application I've seen) can lead to wildly incorrect coefficients and inferences (standard errors or whatever) since most estimators are then both biased and inconsistent. Recommend grabbing https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262296793/econometric-analysis-of-cross-section-and-panel-data/ or https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-52452-8 for R examples as well.

Comment: The interaction I expect to see is that when activity is low, the environmental variables play a role in counts on a daily time period whereas when activity is high, they don't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interaction in logistic regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699592/interaction-in-logistic-regression-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

1. The formula you proposed at the end of your question has an interaction but it also includes redundant terms that will drop out of the model because of perfect collinearity. If you want a multiplicative interaction, you need to multiply the model terms. You can use `*` as short-hand to include both the main terms and the interaction term. For example, `y~x*z` is equivalent to `y ~ x + z + x:z` with `x:z` being equivalent to element-wise multiplication of the vectors `x` and `z`. If you don't want the main terms and only want the interaction, you can just do `y ~ x:z`.
2. If you have other variables that do not interact with each other or the other variables that are interacted, then you just enter them into the model formula, separated by `+`.  For example, you can add `w` with: `y ~ x*z + w`.
3. If you're using a Poisson model, for example, you could put all of this together into something like: `glm(counts ~ activity*temp + percip, family="poisson", data = foo))`. This will estimate an intercept, the main term coefficients (partial derivative of activity when temp = 0 and partial derivative of temp when activity = 0), and the interaction (how the partial derivative for one variable changes with with the other variable's levels.
4. It sounds like you might not understand the statistical model you wish to fit. This website is not for statistics questions, but you can check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/ if you want feedback on your specific statistical model. That being said, there's some serious statistical misunderstanding going on here that I'll save for a comment instead.

Comment: Please provide the comment. Ecological modeling is not my primary work and so I'm learning on the fly. I think I have an understanding of what I want to do and why, just not how to get there from here. Thanks for the stack exchange link.